# MySql gridview delete command

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, .net, webforms

I have this `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Delete" 
                            onclientclick="javascript:return confirm('are you sure you want to delete.');" 
                            Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="first" HeaderText="first" SortExpression="first" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="last" HeaderText="last" SortExpression="last" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="gender" 
                SortExpression="gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="birthday" HeaderText="birthday" 
                SortExpression="birthday" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:clientConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:clientConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Client;" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Client WHERE id = @id AND email = @email;">

        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And when i try to excute a delete i get this error:

```
Parameter '@id' must be defined. 
Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '@id' must be defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add the `DataKeyNames` attribute to your GridView

You must set the DataKeyNames property in order for the automatic update and delete features of the GridView control to work. The values of these key fields are passed to the data source control in order to specify the row to update or delete. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

```
DataKeyNames="id,email"
```

In the context of your Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None"  DataKeyNames="id,email">
```